# Question about higher order mean field equation $\left(-\Delta_{g}\right)^{m} u+\lambda=\lambda \frac{e^{2 m u}}{\int_{M} e^{2 m u} d \mu_{g}}$ .

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I'm reading Dr.Luca Martinazzi's paper
[Existence of solutions to a higher dimensional
mean-field equation on manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.5231)
which proves that for $m \geq 1$, there is an existence result for the equation
$$
\left(-\Delta_{g}\right)^{m} u+\lambda=\lambda \frac{e^{2 m u}}{\int_{M} e^{2 m u} d \mu_{g}}
$$
on a closed Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ of dimension $2 m$ for certain values of $\lambda$.

This is a little strange for me, when dimension becomes higher, we need the $m$'s power of $\Delta$:$\left(-\Delta_{g}\right)^{m} $  to obtain the existence of the solution.

What happens when we just consider the equation
$$
-\Delta_{g} u+\lambda=\lambda \frac{e^{2  u}}{\int_{M} e^{2  u} d \mu_{g}}
$$
on higher dimension manifold?

Comment: Just look at the proof and see where it goes wrong. My best guess is that you need high enough integrability of the derivates of $u$ to make Sobolev embeddings/inequalities work. At first glance, I would examine the Adams-Moser-Trudinger inequality and the energy functional more closely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I read the proof and it is the Adams-Moser-Trudinger inequality part which require the $m$'s power of $\Delta$.

Comment: I'm just curious about the equation $-\Delta_{g} u+\lambda=\lambda \frac{e^{2 u}}{\int_{M} e^{2 u} d \mu_{g}}$ on higher dimension manifold.

Comment: The energy functional might no longer be bounded below, but it might be quite tedious to find such a sequence going to "$-\infty$".

Comment: Does the energy functional no longer being bounded below means no solution?

Comment: If you are doing a variational approach and try to minimize the energy to get a solution to your PDE: Then the answer is generally yes. 
I do wanna mention you can still search for other critical points of the energy, but those are harder to come by.

Comment: I'm just curious how to prove a PDE is not solvable in some function space, at first I thought if I can construct a sequence in this space to let the energy functional tends to $-\infty$ then there is no solution in this space but as you said I can still search for 'other critical points', I'm confused what are they, maybe I need more knowledge about variation method.

Comment: I dont think there is an easy way of making sure a functional on an infinite-dimensional space has no critical point. 
However, you could assume a solution to the PDE exists in some reasonable function class and then try to obtain a contradiction. Since you lack regularity, a good idea might be to search of a blow-up.